Перемещение игрока на конкретные координаты при смене сцены C#
У меня игра, на юнити, где игрок может зайти в здание и его перенесёт на другую сцену, но когда он выходит обратно (то есть обратно на сцену начала), то игрок оказывается на позиции где был со старта игры, а не перед домом, где должен быть.
Я уже пробовал сделать чекпоинт, но он не помог, я примерно представляю, что положение игрока надо будет записать в переменную, а потом выгружать при обратном переходе, но совершенно без понятия как это сделать.
Если есть идеи, желательно на примерах, то заранее спасибо. Пытаюсь в C# около трёх недель, мб для объяснений это важно.

Ну запомните координаты при выходе со сцены в какой-то отдельный объект, после захода назад на сцену проверьте, есть ли сохраненные координаты, загрузите их. Если нет, используйте координаты спавна по умолчанию.

Этот вопрос похож на: Переход между локациями. Если вы считаете его другим, пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чётко обозначив отличие и/или почему ответы на вопрос не помогли в вашем случае.
